# What should .net framework version be for an addin targeting only Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

The projects in an Addin solution, targeting only Visual Studio 2010 can have .net framework 3.5 or 4.0?

Does this cause a problem?

PS: And are there any restrictions for TFS integrated addin versions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You target 4.0:

Per the [plugin migration document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512930%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from Microsoft:

> Update the following project properties. (In the Solution Explorer, under the project node, click Properties.)
>   in the Application tab, change TargetFramework to the .NET Framework 4

You may find significant value in the [Visual Studio Integration SDK documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Best of luck.